# Using menu to upload files

Tags: php, html

Hey guys so I am having a problem regarding the upload. Okay so I know the basic upload would go something like this

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then a small PHP script to upload the actual file (saving etc..)
Now the problem is that I dont want to use a input to do this, is there a way to do it without the input? Such as having a menu (paragraph href) then just simply click on it and use it to upload? Because I want to do this using a single line on the page, such as "change profile picture" and they select that, ka boom. I dont want to have like 2 buttons for it.

Comment: You need `<input type="file" />` to upload. Period.

Comment: you can probably style the form required any way you want,

Comment: Well I was thinking of having the display none, then when you select the "Chose a picture" it will dissapear and "Upload " will appear but the problem is, I cannot remove the "No file chosen"

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the form, and have any element trigger it via javascript/jQuery:

```
///html

    <p class="form">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt perferendis harum laboriosam, tempora expedita, quis reiciendis quos, vel non inventore voluptate velit? Expedita, asperiores impedit.
</p>
<form action="//" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display: none">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

///javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#fileToUpload').trigger('click');
  })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x3fecnqy/

Answer (score 0):

So you want to submit and upload in one button . Like inside menu here is a demo

[fiddleWithOutPrivew](http://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/0ewLtnyz/) If you want to upload using a thumb show- here another [FiddlewithTHumbview](http://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/0ewLtnyz/2/)

```js
 $('#upload').on('click', function() {
  $('#fileToUpload').trigger('click');

});
$('#upload').change(function() {
  $('#img_up').submit();
});
```

```css
form {
  display: none;
}

header {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover,
.menu a:focus,
.menu a:active {
  color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <header class="header">
  <ul class="menu">

    <li><a id="upload" href="#">upload</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<form action="//" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="img_up">

  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```